# Counting derangements efficiently (the number of permutations of n elements with no fixed points)

Tags: arrays, data-structures, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I have a number n and i want to find number of ways i can create an array having n distinct elements from 1 to n such that for no index i we have A[i] = i.

For example
n = 4 we have 9 permutations
[ 2 1 4 3 ] ,[ 2 3 4 1 ],[ 2 4 1 3 ],[ 3 1 4 2 ],[ 3 4 1 2 ],[ 3 4 2 1 ],[ 4 1 2 3 ],[ 4 3 1 2 ],[ 4 3 2 1 ].

I know the brute force approach which will have time complexity O(n!). Is there any other optimized way of doing this? Something  in  O(n) or O(nlogn) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

A permutation of {1,2,...,n} in which no element occurs in its position is called a *derangement*.  You are looking for the number of derangements of an n-element set, for which there is a formula (which can be obtained using the inclusion-exclusion principle).  The formula is $n! \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i / i!$. See the [Wikipedia article on derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), which derives this formula.

In the limit, this value approaches n!/e, which is approximately 0.37 n!, i.e 37% of the n! permutations would be derangements.

Answer (score 0):

The *Counting Derangements* problem can be solved in linear time O(n) using dynamic programming, thanks to Euler who proved the recurrence relation :

```
!n = (n-1) * (!(n-1) + !(n-2))
```

This allows to solve the problem from bottom up instead of recursively, keeping track of the 2 preceding terms `!(n-1)` and `!(n-2)` (eg. in javascript) :

```js
function a(n) {
  if (n < 3) {
    return n < 0 ? undefined : Math.abs(n-1);
  }

  // For n = 3, we got :
  let x = 1; // !(n-1)
  let y = 0; // !(n-2)

  for (let k=3; k<=n; k++) {
    const fk = (k - 1) * (x + y);
    [x, y] = [fk, x];
  }

  return x;
}
```

Euler also proved another recurrence relation :

```
!n = n * !(n-1) + (-1)^n
```

Using the same technique, there is only one preceding term (variable) to track. This translates to :

```js
function a(n) {
  if (n < 3) {
    return n < 0 ? undefined : Math.abs(n-1);
  }

  let x = 1; // !(n-1) for n = 3

  for (let k=3; k<=n; k++) {
    x = k*x + (-1)**k;
  }

  return x;
}
```